# How can I create a file with a specific size from a command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I create a file (e.g. using the `touch` command or another similar way), but with a specific size (e.g. 14 MB)?

The use case is to test FTP with various file sizes. If we can create a file with a specific size, it will be useful to verify FTP transfer etc.

Comment: Related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Use [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate):

```
truncate -s 14M filename
```

From `man truncate`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Shrink or extend the size of each FILE to the specified size

[...]

 -s, --size=SIZE
          set or adjust the file size by SIZE
```

Note: `truncate` may not be available on your system, e.g. on Mac OS X it's not installed by default (but you can easily install it, using macports for example). In these cases you may need to use `dd` or `head` instead.

Comment: Very nice indeed. The `touch` is not needed though, you can simply run `truncate -s 14M filename` it will create `filename` directly.

Comment: This seems to create a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), whereas the below answer (that uses "dd") doesn't.  I don't know if the difference is important to you, but I figured I'd point it out

Comment: @offby1 Thanks! I was wondering why this file size change wasn't showing up in the output of `df -h`.

Comment: truncate -s 16M MyTestFile.txt 
du -h MyTestFile.txt 
4,0K MyTestFile.txt                                                         Please why du -h does not work in this case ? Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 103):

EDIT: The simplest way is probably the `truncate` of Ashutosh Vishwa Bandhu's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/609025/151431), but as pointed out by [@offby1](https://superuser.com/users/26991/offby1) that creates [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) which may not be what you want. The solutions below create normal, full files.

---

The following commands create a 14MB file called `foo`:

1. `fallocate` (thanks to [@Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough) who suggested it in the comments and vote up Ahmed Masud's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/609353/151431) below which also mentions it.)

   ```
   fallocate -l 14000000 foo
   ```

   This command is particularly impressive since it is as fast as `truncate` (instantaneous) irrespective of the desired file size (unlike the other solutions which will be slow for large files) and yet creates normal files, not sparse ones :

   ```
   $ truncate -s 14MB foo1.txt 
   $ fallocate -l 14000000 foo2.txt 
   $ ls -ls foo?.txt 
       0 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 14000000 Jun 21 03:54 foo1.txt
   13672 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 14000000 Jun 21 03:55 foo2.txt
   ```
2. Create a file filled with random data

   ```
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=14MB count=1
   ```

   or

   ```
   head -c 14MB /dev/urandom > foo
   ```
3. Create a file filled with `\0`s:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.txt bs=14MB count=1
   ```

   or

   ```
   head -c 14MB /dev/zero > foo
   ```
4. Create a file filled with the first 14MB of data of another file:

   ```
   head -c 14MB bar.txt > foo
   ```
5. Create a file filled with the last 14MB of data of another file:

   ```
   tail -c 14MB bar.txt > foo
   ```

---

In all of the above examples, the file will be `14*1000*1000` if you want `14*1024*1024`, replace `MB` with `M`. For example:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=14M count=1
head -c 14M /dev/zero > foo
```

`fallocate` only deals in bytes, so you'd have to do (14*1024*1024=14680064)

```
fallocate -l 14680064 foo
```

Comment: Thanks... This will also meet my purpose of creating a file of desired size...

Comment: @fasil which one will you accept?

Comment: I've tried 
head -c 14MB /dev/zero > 14mb.txt
and i get

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 14000000 giu 18 17:33 14mb.txt

 So M stand for 1000 and not 1024?

Comment: @FabioF. yes, if you want 1024, use `M` instead of `MB`. See `man head` or `man tail`.

Comment: i'd recommend against the use of `dd` if there is a simpler, less potentially-destructive approach.

Comment: @acolyte so would I. That's why each `dd` solution has a non-dd alternative.

Comment: The wiki entry says than even dd (with zeros) will create a sparse file, doesn't it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: @terdon Neither tail nor head says anything about M and MB over here. Just logically, it would make more sense if M meano 10^6 and MB 1024^2.

Comment: @Michael I checked, just to be sure, and none of my commands produces sparse files. The `dd` command on the wiki page is completely different and does not use `/dev/zero`.  As for whether `M` or `MB` is more logical, take it up with the developers. The man pages of [head](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head), [tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) and [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) all clearly state that "MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024". This may be different on other *nixes.

Comment: [`fallocate` is also another good alternative](http://linuxreviews.org/man/fallocate/), and is probably the quickest for larger files that don't require initialization with random data (from the SO question linked to under a comment in the OP).

Comment: @Breakthrough yeah, wow, `fallocate` seems to be the best by far.

Answer (score 21):

```
dd bs=1MB count=14 if=/dev/zero of=<yourfilename>
```

**WARNING** `dd` will silently overwrite *anything* you have the rights to write to, if you specify it either willingly or by accident. Make sure you understand `dd`, eg. with reading `dd --help`, and you don't screw up your dd command lines or else you can easily create irreversible data loss - *even total*.

For start, `if=` is the *input file* and `of=` is the *output file*. *Always* double check that you got it right, before running the command. :)

Answer (score 13):

Use magic `dd` ;) [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1024  count=14336
```

cause 14MB*1024 = 14336KB, or:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1MB  count=14
```

And you'll get 14mb output.dat file, filled with zeroes :D

Answer (score 8):

This should be the fastest way to do it:

```
SEEK=$SIZE-1
dd if=/dev/zero of=outfile bs=1 seek=$SEEK count=1
```

Otherwise just write a quick and dirty C or perl program that does a seek to the exact position and writes a single byte. This is a LOT faster than actually dumping data onto the blocks.

If you want to avoid sparse files then on Linux (and possibly other systems) you can use `fallocate -l <length>` from `util-linux`.

If that's unavailable, and you have a POSIX compliant system then you can write a quick and dirty program using posix_fallocate() library call. posix_fallocate guarantees allocation of the range specified so you will not get a disk-full on subsequent use of the range if it returns successfully

Answer (score 7):

While `dd` is the portable way to do it, the commands [`mkfile`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/8/mkfile/) and [`xfs_mkfile`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_mkfile) are written specifically for this purpose and are faster:

```
mkfile size[b|k|m|g] filename
xfs_mkfile size[b|k|m|g] filename
```

The catch is that neither command is universally available, so they are not good for writing portable scripts.  However, if I'm doing it interactively via the command line, those are the commands I use.

By default they create zero-filled files and not [sparse (or "holey") files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sparse_file).  They both take the `-n` option to create sparse files instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option with Perl:

`perl -e 'print "a" x 1024' > file.txt`

This will create 1KB file. Replace 1024 with any number you like.

Comment: I found this useful because I can create a file with "readable" contents, not just arbitrary contents.