# Filling up the hard drive until certain amount of space is left?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, shell-script, batch-file

I'm doing some testing of a product on Apple and Android devices.
I'd like a script that will fill up the devices hard drive until 100KB space is left on the drive it's runs against to. Also in linux systems I use 
dd if=/dev/zero of=zeros bs=1M to fill up the hdd entirely, but.. 
How do I make it fill up the hdd until certain amount of space is left?
I'd like this both for linux command line or a bat script(windows) 
Example of a shell script and a windows batch script would be the best!
Thanks!

Comment: First allocate a file for the "reserved" space, then fill the drive.  When the drive is full, delete the reserved file.

Comment: Can please you be more specific ? For example. I want script to fill it up until 100kb is left

Comment: A BAT file with a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to write a real file, or are dummy files sufficient?  The `dd` method you're using is going to be pretty slow for large drives . . .

In Windows, you can use `fsutil file createnew <filename> <length_in_bytes>` which will create a filler file.  Here's a [technet page with some more details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788058.aspx).

In linux, `fallocate` works similarly, e.g. `fallocate -l 10G 10gig_filler`.  Here's a [previous SU question](https://superuser.com/q/609020/151431) on creating filler files, as well as a [slightly more technical version on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system).

Comment: `fallocate` actually creates a non-sparse file, but only if your filesystem supports that syscall (otherwise it just fails). `ext4` and `xfs` are the only really common filesystems that support it.

Comment: fsutil creates sparse file, not filling HDD with real zero bytes!

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you could do something like this to leave only 1M*:

```
avail=$( df --output=source,avail -BM | grep sda6 | 
        awk '{print $NF}' | sed s/M//i); size=$((avail-left)  ); 
fallocate -l $sizeM filler_file;
```

The trick is parsing `df` to get the space available and then using `fallocate` to create a file of the necessary size. However, as @jjlin [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/686638/filling-up-the-hard-drive-until-certain-amount-of-space-is-left#comment871331_686644), the `fallocate` call will not work on all filesystems.

You can turn the little script above into a function to make it easier to use and also have it use an [alternative method](https://superuser.com/a/609024/151431) to create the file when on a filesystem that does not support `fallocate` (though `fallocate` is *much* faster and should be preferred where possible). Just add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent for other shells):

```
fill_disk(){
    ## The space you want left
    left=$1 
    ## The unit you are using (Units are K, M, G,  T,  P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024) or 
    ## KB, MB, ... (powers of 1000).
    unit=$2 
    ## The target drive
    disk=$3 
    ## The file name to create, make sure it is on the right drive.
    outfile=$4
    ## The space currently available on the target drive
    avail=$(df --output=source,avail -B$unit | grep $disk | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s/$unit//i); 
    ## The size of the file to be created
    size=$((avail-left))
    ## Skip if the available free space is already less than what requested
    if [ "$size" -gt 0 ]; then
    ## Use fallocate if possible, fall back to head otherwise
    fallocate -l $size$unit $outfile 2>/dev/null || head -c $size$unit /dev/zero > $outfile
    else 
    echo "There is already less then $left space available on $disk"
    fi
}
```

You can then launch it like this:

fill_disk desired_free_space unit target_disk out_file

For example, to create a file called `/foo.txt` that will leave only 100M free on `/` (`sda1`), run

```
fill_disk 100 M sda1 /foo.txt
```

Just **make sure the target file is on the drive you want to fill**, the function does not check for that.

<sup>* I couldn't get it to work reliably for small sizes, either it would run out of space or give me slightly different values from those I requested.</sup>

---

As requested, here's the same thing as a script:

```
#!/bin/env/bash
left=$1 
unit=$2 
disk=$3 
outfile=$4
avail=$(df --output=source,avail -B$unit | grep $disk | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s/$unit//i); 
size=$((avail-left))
if [ "$size" -gt 0 ]; then
  fallocate -l $size$unit $outfile 2>/dev/null || head -c $size$unit /dev/zero > $outfile
else 
  echo "There is already less then $left space available on $disk"
fi
```

Save it as `fill_disk.sh` and run like this:

```
bash fill_disk.sh 100 M sda1 /foo.txt
```

Comment: Terdon: Can I use this as a shell script ? So I can use the script on multiple machines without having to modify /.bashrc ?

Comment: @Rubynator sure, just copy everything except the opening `fill_disk(){` and closing `}` into a file and add `#!/bin/env/bash` to the top of that file and it's a script.

Comment: Sure but can I still use the parameters like the above example you gave? Please confirm the correct usage. Thanks

Comment: @Rubynator see updated answer.

Comment: Great! What about the windows version (bat file) any ideas?

Comment: @Rubynator none, sorry, I don't use Windows.